# Dropbox Datastore API Internal Error on iOS: assert failed

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am trying to make a global way of setting up a datastore observer from any view controller.

I call the method like this:

```
//SomeViewController.m
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  [[PPDropboxSync sharedDropboxSync] listenForDropboxChangesInController:self];
}
```

..and it executes like this:

```
//PPDropboxSync.m
-(void)listenForDropboxChangesInController:(id)controller
{
  if([self isDropboxLinked]){
    //Get the dropbox datastore session
    [self openDatastore];

    __weak typeof(controller) weakController = controller;
    __weak DBDatastore *weakStore = self.store;

    [weakStore addObserver:weakController block:^(){

      if(weakStore.status & DBDatastoreIncoming){
        //The sync returns a dictionary of affected tables, each with a collection of changed records
        NSDictionary *changes = [weakStore sync:nil];

        //Process changes...

      }
      //Update sync time
      [self updateSyncTime];
    }];        
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error on this line: `NSDictionary *changes = [weakStore sync:nil];`

...that says:

> [ERROR] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_INTERNAL: database.cpp:317: database.cpp:317: assert failed: record
>   Assertion failed: (!"record"), function apply_changes, file /ws/syncsdk/common/ssync/database.cpp, line 317.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you please open a ticket with your app ID, user ID, and steps to reproduce? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact Thanks in advance!

Comment: For anyone also seeing this issue, please upgrade to the latest version, currently 3.0.2: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync